# WebDriver start several driver instances

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have 4 selenium projects that starts from command line using TestNG at same time.

3 of 4 started successfully, but 1 of them has "Failed Configuration" error and finished with **"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms"** - in driver.get(url)

Could somebody please suggest me what is the reason of this failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this problem before. I isolated it to Firefox and running tests in parallel. I don't rightly recall what I did to eliminate the problem, but I believe I solved it by doing one of the following things (start at the top and if that doesn't help, move to the next item).

(1) Try only limiting Firefox's max instances to 1 or 2, if that stops your problem, you not it is limited to firefox.
(2) Try going back to a version of Firefox that is one or two generations old.
(3) On your hub (or also on your node) try setting timeout to 45 and browserTimeout to 60.

If I get a chance, I'll try to look at my setup and see how I ended up fixing the problem.